# Where to check for foreign keys: at PHP by additional queries, or let MySQL to raise an error?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreign-keys

Which is the best way to handle `FOREIGN KEY` errors on database `INSERT`?

1. Before `INSERT` by PHP: load additional queries (`SELECT`) that checks for foreign key matches?
2. Let MySQL to raise and error, and PDO to throw an exception?
3. More option exists?

Compare to speed/elegance/reusable code/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times 1) is not an option. Imagine you have People that attend to Meetings. If you have a PeopleMeetings table (M to N association), you can't do a SELECT and then an INSERT... b/c you may do a SELECT and find that both the Person and the Meeting exist, then another process could delete the meeting and you would then do the INSERT, which would fail b/c the Meeting no longer exist.

This is why I always do 2)... obviously, if the meeting does not exist, I would do a SELECT before loading the page, to show the user the Meetings currently on the system, but doing 2) is def a must.

Not to mention that you don't need to do 2 more extra queries (on my example) one to People and another to Meeting... and you can still handle the error gracefully, giving the user information of what went wrong (as you would do if you did the 2 SELECT queries)

Also, you should use transactions... so that if you were doing changes on the db and this INSERT fails, the transaction is rolled back and the database is not left in an unconsistent state

Comment: I always fire a transaction this case, of course, when I'm dealing with `INSERT` and `FOREIGN KEY`'s. I must mention, my clients always loaded with rich Javascript form/input validation modules, so in a sunny day I don't have to worry about user-friendly error reporting, 'cause they stuck at form submitting. When they troll the input, and `FOREIGN KEY` fails... well... who cares about trolls? I just throw them an 'input error' default display. User-friendly error reporting is just an unnecessary move to me.

Comment: cool :) even if you had to deal with user-friendly error reporting, I still think that doing the INSERT and then handling the error is the way to go... b/c between the SELECT and the INSERT, the DB data may have changed (b/c of other users' interactions). You may need to do "something" if the insert failed

Comment: even if you don't have to do anything after the INSERT fails, you would be doing 2 unnecessary SELECT queries... what would you gain by doing those queries?

Answer (score 1):

It always makes sense to check errors that you're aware could be a possibility well before you touch the database, so I'd say option 1 is the best bet.  It also gives you more user friendly error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to be "user-friendly" and display usefull error-messages, I would say 1.

Of course, the answer will depend on your context...